# How can I turn a Task into a PageAsyncTask in C# 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, asp.net-4.0, pageasynctask

The following doesn't compile. This is for asynchronous calls in a **4.0**, **aspx WebForms page**.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(100));
var pat = new PageAsyncTask(task); //Doesn't compile, no such signature.
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(pat);
```

Google searching is failing me because of all the irrelevant 4.5 material that I can't use. By that I mean, I can't use 4.5.

If I just use a Task without RegisterAsyncTask, I get a warning that bare Tasks are not supported in WebForms, or it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.  Instead of constructing PageAsyncTask with a task, construct it with a method that returns the task, like so:

`var pat = new PageAsyncTask(() => Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(100)));`

For .Net 4.0:

`Action a = () => Thread.Sleep(100);
var p = new PageAsyncTask((s, e, cb, o) => a.BeginInvoke(cb, o), a.EndInvoke, null, null);`

Comment: This doesn't compile in 4.0, Task.Run is 4.5. Also, PageAsyncTask is reporting that it can't convert a lambda to a delegate.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a solution for .net 4.0